# How to include search function in drop down box?

Tags: jquery, jscript

i am using a dropdown box with usernames,i want to include search function in the dropdown box where we have to search by name instead of scrolling?
how can i do that? i am using this code but i am not getting the right output.

For this i am using the following code .

```
<head>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }

    .searchbox {
        border: 1px solid #456879;
        border-radius: 6px;
        height: 22px;
        width: 200p;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
</style>


<script>

    (function ($) {

        $.fn.searchit = function (options) {

            return this.each(function () {

                $.fn.searchit.globals = $.fn.searchit.globals || {
                    counter: 0
                }
                $.fn.searchit.globals.counter++;
                var $counter = $.fn.searchit.globals.counter;

                var $t = $(this);
                var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.searchit.defaults, options);

                // Setup default text field and class
                if (opts.textField == null) {
                    $t.before("<input type='textbox' id='__searchit" + $counter + "'><br>");
                    opts.textField = $('#__searchit' + $counter);
                }
                if (opts.textField.length > 1) opts.textField = $(opts.textField[0]);

                if (opts.textFieldClass) opts.textField.addClass(opts.textFieldClass);
                //MY CODE-------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (opts.selected) opts.textField.val($(this).find(":selected").val());
                //MY CODE ENDS HERE -------------------------------------------------------
                if (opts.dropDown) {
                    $t.css("padding", "5px")
                        .css("margin", "-5px -20px -5px -5px");

                    $t.wrap("<div id='__searchitWrapper" + $counter + "' />");
                    opts.wrp = $('#__searchitWrapper' + $counter);
                    opts.wrp.css("display", "inline-block")
                        .css("vertical-align", "top")
                        .css("overflow", "hidden")
                        .css("border", "solid grey 1px")
                        .css("position", "absolute")
                        .hide();
                    if (opts.dropDownClass) opts.wrp.addClass(opts.dropDownClass);
                }

                opts.optionsFiltered = [];
                opts.optionsCache = [];

                // Save listbox current content
                $t.find("option").each(function (index) {
                    opts.optionsCache.push(this);
                });

                // Save options
                $t.data('opts', opts);

                // Hook listbox click
                $t.click(function (event) {
                    _opts($t).textField.val($(this).find(":selected").text());
                    _opts($t).wrp.hide();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

                // Hook html page click to close dropdown
                $("html").click(function () {
                    _opts($t).wrp.hide();
                });

                // Hook the keyboard and we're done
                _opts($t).textField.keyup(function (event) {
                    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                        $(this).val($t.find(":selected").text());
                        _opts($t).wrp.hide();
                        return;
                    }
                    setTimeout(_findElementsInListBox($t, $(this)), 50);
                })

            })


            function _findElementsInListBox(lb, txt) {

                if (!lb.is(":visible")) {
                    _showlb(lb);
                }

                _opts(lb).optionsFiltered = [];
                var count = _opts(lb).optionsCache.length;
                var dropDown = _opts(lb).dropDown;
                var searchText = txt.val().toLowerCase();

                // find match (just the old classic loop, will make the regexp later)
                $.each(_opts(lb).optionsCache, function (index, value) {
                    if ($(value).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
                        // save matching items
                        _opts(lb).optionsFiltered.push(value);
                    }

                    // Trigger a listbox reload at the end of cycle
                    if (!--count) {
                        _filterListBox(lb);
                    }
                });
            }

            function _opts(lb) {
                return lb.data('opts');
            }

            function _showlb(lb) {
                if (_opts(lb).dropDown) {
                    var tf = _opts(lb).textField;
                    lb.attr("size", _opts(lb).size);
                    _opts(lb).wrp.show().offset({
                        top: tf.offset().top + tf.outerHeight(),
                        left: tf.offset().left
                    });
                    _opts(lb).wrp.css("width", tf.outerWidth() + "px");
                    lb.css("width", (tf.outerWidth() + 25) + "px");
                }
            }

            function _filterListBox(lb) {
                lb.empty();

                if (_opts(lb).optionsFiltered.length == 0) {
                    lb.append("<option>" + _opts(lb).noElementText + "</option>");
                } else {
                    $.each(_opts(lb).optionsFiltered, function (index, value) {
                        lb.append(value);
                    });
                    lb[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        $.fn.searchit.defaults = {
            textField: null,
            textFieldClass: null,
            dropDown: true,
            dropDownClass: null,
            size: 5,
            filtered: true,
            noElementText: "No elements found",
            //MY CODE------------------------------------------
            selected: false
            //MY CODE ENDS ------------------------------------
        }

    }(jQuery))

    $("select").searchit({
        textFieldClass: 'searchbox',
        selected: true
    });

</script>


</head>

<body>

Type the search text:
<br />
<select id="listBox1">
    <option>Robinhood</option>
    <option>Rockford</option>
    <option>Rome</option>
    <option>Ronda</option>
    <option>Rondon</option>
    <option>Rondonopolis</option>
    <option>Rongelap</option>
</select>
<br>Second searchbox
<br>
<select id="listBox2">
    <option>Robinhood</option>
    <option>Rockford</option>
    <option>Rome</option>
    <option>Ronda</option>
    <option>Rondon</option>
    <option>Rondonopolis</option>
    <option>Rongelap</option>
</select>


</body>
```

but when i execute this code,

it wont allow me to type and search,it is showing like ordinary Dropdown box.what i have to do??
give me some solutions for this.

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery plugin [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: thanks for your reply..i ll check it.

Answer (score 0):

You better use [JQuery Autocomplete widget](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) **instead** of select-box. You can see full documentation on the [API documentation page](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).